# MSSQL group rows with different values by "updating" those values

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, case, sql-server-2017

Assume following data:

[image]

This data needs to be grouped to get this result:

[image]

As you can see, the `id` is simply aggregated with `STRING_AGG(id, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id ASC)`. The `accountNums` are a bit trickier. Only if a `refNum` has the 2 `accountNum`s `10040` and `10041`, then they should be replaced by the value `2`. If any `refNum` has onl one of these `accountNums`, then they should not be replaced. The same goes for any other `accountNum`.

I tried following SQL query, but I can't group it properly:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(f.id, ' ') WITHIN GROUP ( 
ORDER BY f.id ASC),
f.refNum,
CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (   SELECT 1 
                    FROM Foo f2 
                    WHERE (f2.accountNum = 10040 
                        OR f2.accountNum = 10041) 
                        AND f2.id != f.id) 
    AND (f.accountNum = 10040 
    OR f.accountNum = 10041) 
    THEN 2 
    ELSE f.accountNum 
END AS accountNumUpdated,
SUM(f.value) AS val 
FROM Foo f 
GROUP BY f.refNum,
    accountNumUpdated
```

The issue with this query is that `accountNumUpdated` is not known in the `GROUP BY` clause. Also I can't move the `CASE WHEN` into the `GROUP BY`, as the subquery is not allowed there either.

As I couldn't find any way around these issues, the question is, **how do I need to change the query to get the result I want?**

The exact SQL server version is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64) 
    Aug 22 2017 17:04:49 
    Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
```

---

<sub>If anything is unclear, don't hesitate to ask</sub>

Comment: What if  a `refNum` has the 3+  `accountNums` `10040` and `10041` ?

Comment: @Serg you mean `10040`, `10040`, `10041` for example? in that case all 3 should be grouped together. It would be assumed that both `10040` should in fact be a single row. Thus, in the end it would all turn out to be a single row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `cte` on your result. Since you already computed your value

```
; WITH CTE AS (
SELECT f.id,
f.refNum,
CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (   SELECT 1 
                    FROM Foo f2 
                    WHERE (f2.accountNum = 10040 
                        OR f2.accountNum = 10041) 
                        AND f2.id != f1.id
                        AND f2.refNum = f1.refNum)   --- add this since you want to combine for one refno 
    AND (f.accountNum = 10040 
    OR f.accountNum = 10041) 
    THEN 2 
    ELSE f.accountNum 
END) AS accountNumUpdated,
f.value AS val 
FROM Foo f group by f.id, f.refnum, f.value
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(id, ' ') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY id ASC) , 
max(refNum) as refNum,  max(accountNumUpdated) as accountNumUpdated , sum(val) as val 
FROM CTE GROUP BY accountNumUpdated
```

Comment: This does look pretty good already, but it seems I have a mistake in my `CASE WHEN`, as I always get `accountNum` = 2 when its either 10041 or 10040, even if there is no second row. Any idea where I did wrong?

Comment: can you post the output you are getting from your query

Comment: I again checked my ans, and analyse that may be you dont need any group by

Comment: I just tested your new solution and I had to include an `GROUP BY accountNumUpdated`, because otherwise it would just result in a single result. I need to do some further tests to see if this truly works

Comment: I tested a bit further and the result is completely off. Going form like 400 rows to 13. and they are definitly not properly grouped. I will add some results to illustrate the issue that persists with the `CASE WHEN`

Comment: if possible then make a fiddle and give the link.

Comment: I found part of my issue and got it quite fixed. Yet I still have the `CASE WHEN` issue. [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/de11af/7) which shows the issue on row 3

Comment: you need to add inner join on refnum also, since for each refnum your record is updated. update in fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/de11af/9

Comment: I found 1 edge case which I just can't reproduce in SQL fiddle. But I think that already awesome enough. Thanks mate!